# red group name color

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ide, bundle

**Xcode** shows group name with red color.

[image]
[image]

*How to remove this or make it normal*

I am using **Xcode** **9**

Comment: I see there is a triangle next to it but is the folder empty or not and if it's not empty are the files in it ok or also red?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson please refer my question, i updated with new image

Comment: Personally I would make sure I have a backup of those files before I do anything. Then I would move the files out of the folder and try to delete the Feed folder and recreate it.

Comment: Try removing folder from Xcode and re-add it back. This happens usually when you rename a folder either from Xcode or physically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically this problem occurs when folder miss match with original path

**Step 1** Select red folder/group

**Step 2** Select file inspector from right panel of Xcode and click Folder icon

[image]

**Step 3** Choose correct path and enjoy...

Answer (score -2):

Use Below Steps:-

- In Xcode Right click on Feed -> Show in Finder -> Copy all content
- In Xcode Right click on Feed -> Delete -> Move to Trash
- Go in Show in Finder where you have to create folder -> Create folder with name Feed -> Paste copied content -> Drag Feed folder to Xcode.